# Strange behaviour when scrolling just one time UITableView. Can't scroll anymore

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

So, I've got an `UITableView` with a Custom Cell

[image]

and this is my View Hierarchy:

[image]

So, the last view on the top is part of the Custom Cell.

Now I scroll (just touch up, or scroll a little bit), and I get this new View Hierarchy:

[image]

I'm getting a last `UIView` which is not letting me scroll anymore.

Any clue of what is it?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, solved.

It was because of it was an instance of [MMDrawerController](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController).